# Find an orthonormal basis for $\Bbb R^3$ where $q$ has a diagonal form

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

This seemed like a classic question of diagonalization, however I am a bit confused here since my result does not match my goal.

> Let $\left(\begin{matrix} 3 & -1 & 0\\ -1 & 2 & -1 \\ 0 & -1 & 3\end{matrix} \right)$ be a matrix.
>
> 1. Find the quadratic form $q:\Bbb R^3\to \Bbb R$ where q is represented by A.
> 2. Find an orthonormal basis of $\Bbb R^3$ where $q$ has a diagonal form (i.e represented by a diagonal matrix).

**"Solution"**

1. The quadratic form is the following:

$$q(A)=3x_1^2 -2x_1x_2 +2x_2^2 -2x_2x_3 +3x_3^3$$

2. Correct me if I'm wrong but I have to diagonalize the matrix and then perform Gram-Schmidt algorithm. Another option was  use express the quadratic form in a diagonal form (using Lagrange Method) and then use Gram-Schmidt but I have found out it might not be correct).

The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is: $$P_A=(t-4)(t-3)(t-1)$$
If the matrix is diagonalizable then the algebraic and geometric multiplicity were the same, however calculating the eigenspace for the eigenvalues gives different outcome, for example for $t=4$: $$(A-4I)=\left(\begin{matrix} - 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & - 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{matrix} \right) $$
Which gives the basis $$span \left\{\left(1,0,0\right),\left( 0,1,1\right) \right\}$$
Which gives geometric multiplicity of 2 for the eigenvalues $t=4$ which has an algebraic multiplicity of 1.

This means that the matrix is not diagonalizable but I think I am wrong somewhere.

Any ideas where I'm wrong?

Thanks,

Alan

Comment: Your $A-4I$ is wrong.

Comment: The matrix or the final basis? Or both? thank you.

Comment: I have found a mistake indeed, and fixed it, however the basis is still of dimension=2, $span \left\{ (1,0,0),(0,1,1) \right\}$ which is not good for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Your $A-4I$ is wrong. We have:
$$
\left(\begin{matrix} 3 & -1 & 0\\ -1 & 2 & -1 \\ 0 & -1 & 3\end{matrix} \right)- 4\left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{matrix}\right)=
\left(\begin{matrix} 3 & -1 & 0\\ -1 & 2 & -1 \\ 0 & -1 & 3\end{matrix} \right)- \left(\begin{matrix} 4 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 4 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 4\end{matrix}\right)
=
\left(\begin{matrix} -1 & -1 & 0\\ -1 & -2 & -1 \\ 0 & -1 & -1\end{matrix}\right)
$$

Use this and you can find an eigenvector $v_{\lambda=4}=(1,-1,1)^T$:

$$
(a-4I)\vec x=0 \Rightarrow
\left(\begin{matrix} -1 & -1 & 0\\ -1 & -2 & -1 \\ 0 & -1 & -1\end{matrix}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix}x\\ y \\ z\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}0\\ 0 \\ 0\end{matrix}\right) \Rightarrow
$$
$$
\begin{cases}
-x-y=0\\
-x-2y-z=0\\
-y-z=0
\end{cases}
\Rightarrow 
\begin{cases}
x=-y\\
y=-z\\
z=t \in \mathbb{R}
\end{cases}
$$
so the eigenspace is $(t,-t,t)^T$ and an eigenvector is $(1,-1,1)^T$

Comment: Somehow I am still not getting it. The final matrix I get has two rows, meaning I have two vectors in the basis, or can I find a basis with one vector even though the final matrix has two rows? I get $\left(  \begin{matrix}  -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0   \end{matrix}  \right)$

Comment: As noted in my answer your matrix $A-4I$ is wrong and I cannot see how you find this result. I've added something that I hope can be helpful. In you want a more specific help you have to show the work that gives your result.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why when I use gauss elimination I get two rows in my canonical matrix.

Comment: Do you think my way of solving the question is the right one, giving the fact that I use your method on the other eigenvectors?

Comment: Yes, your method is correct. You can see a diagonalization here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=diagonalize+%7B%7B3%2C-1%2C0%7D%2C%7B-1%2C2%2C-1%7D%2C%7B0%2C-1%2C3%7D%7D

Comment: Thank you for all your help.

Comment: OK, found it. The geometric multiplicity equals to $ 3-\rho(A)=1$ since the space here is $ \Bbb R^3$.